# category page template for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I want to create a template for category page for custom post type.
I have tried with category-my-campcat.php and taxonomy-my-campcat.php.

But when I click on category then it redirect to category.php page.

Also How can I check that I am on category page in wordpress. from is_category() ???
I have tried it but no success...

Comment: Ahh it was working. but I found a new problem.

I am using below code to use my own template for detail page of my custom post


`
function my_search_template_redirect() {
 global $post;
  if ($post->post_type == 'my_camp' && !is_search() ) {
 $templatefilename = 'my_camp-template.php';
$return_template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/my_templates/' . $templatefilename;
do_theme_redirect($return_template);
}}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_search_template_redirect', 1);
`

But here how can I check for category page here like:
if ($post->post_type == 'my_camp' && !is_search() && !is_category() )

Comment: what is the post type?

Comment: post type: my_camp

Comment: have u tried this file name taxonomy-my-camp.php

Comment: Please read this post http://wordpress.org/support/topic/category-template-for-custom-post-type

Comment: @avinashphp Please edit your answer and add the full code that solved your problem. Please take those code from comments and add them to the Answer to make it more user-friendly. WPSE Q&A are not just for our personal queries and solutions - it's a source for the future too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I alter my code and use below code to check :

```
if ($post->post_type == 'my_camp' && is_single() ) {
```

Now it will check only for my_camp post type at post detail page